# Force notification of file creation to FAM or lighttpd

Tags: cgi, lighttpd

Environment: Debian, lighttpd, fam. It is unclear whether virtual private server's kernel Dnotify is enabled or not.

After my CGI creates a file in file system, it responds a short message to client, java script running in browser, notifying the client that the file is ready for download. There is one issue here - most of the time the client gets http `404` error from lighttpd especially when all these software run in localhost. I think this problem is caused by the latency of lighttpd being notified by fam of the file creation. I imagine the all events happen in the following sequence:

1. CGI creates a file.
2. CGI responds to client.
3. client fetch the file from lighttpd.
4. lighttpd does not find the file in its cache.

I can imagine that such problem will be worse once the file is created in remote host and is notified to lighttpd via NFS.

My question is: how to code CGI to tell lighttpd about file creation before respond to client?

That is, how do I "insert" a notification step in between above steps `1.` and `2.`?  If I can not do this with lighttpd but I can do it with nginx, I can consider switching to the latter, too. Similarly, I will be fine to switch from fam to other file alternation monitors.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lighttpd is not caching the non-existence of the file, so the problem is more likely in your CGI script.  The CGI script should create the file and should close it so that the kernel knows that the contents should be flushed to disk, as they might still be buffered in stdio in the CGI process.  Only after that should the script send a message to the client.

As you noted, extra steps are required if the CGI is run on a different server from the one that receives the second request for the file, and the file is stored on NFS or other remote filesystem.  The easiest solution is to have the client wait a second or two and retry to download the file a few times, as typical NFS caching settings are about 5 seconds.